# Nicknames in chat appear as "half-cut"

Tags: bug, status-norepro, chat

I'm writing this just after the shut down of all the SE network.

All sites are back online but there is a little problem, which I'm not sure I should call a bug, but that is certainly annoying and no, it wasn't there before the shut down.

This is how my name appears in the chat-flow:

[image]

Is this just me or is it happening to others? I have Lion, using Chrome 18.0.1025.165. Not happening on Firefox 11.0.

Comment: This might also be due to Zoom as I said on your other post, see if that fixes it.

Comment: @BenBrocka Uhm... I think it fixed it. I'm not 100% sure because the effects didn't appear instantly, but I think it did it.

Comment: Did the twitch stop?

Comment: @BenBrocka I don't know about that, since it doesn't happen every time, only sometimes. I'll wait some days and see if it comes again. :)

Comment: FWIW sounds exactly like the problem I had with Zoom as well

Comment: @BenBrocka Yes you told me! Thank you for your help. If you want you can post that as an answer so I can accept it. I'm not 100% sure it was the fix, for the reason I said above, but now they appear nicely, so I think it's the one. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reset your Zoom with Ctrl + 0 and the cut off should stop (⌘ + 0 on a Mac). It's almost certainly zoom weirdness like the problem in [The chat is "flickering"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122778/166936).